# StructureMap and Multi-tier MVC solution

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, structuremap3

I have a structures a project this way:
Data Layer - for models
MVC Website - for all other mvc website related.

I want my controller to inject the database context and the service at the same time and still ensure dependency injection.

Here's my code
My Controller:

```
  private CMSDB _db;
    public HomeController(CMSDB db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }
```

My Database Context

```
  public class CMSDB : DbContext
{
    public CMSDB() : base("DefaultConnection"){   }
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Department> Departments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserDatails> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Module> Modules { get; set; }
}
```

Model in a separate project

```
 public class Module : IModule
{
   public virtual int ID { get; set; }
   public virtual string Name { get; set; }
   public virtual DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
   public virtual string ModuleDescription { get; set; }
}
```

My interface in the same project with the Model

```
 public interface IModule
 {    }
```

I want my controller to inject the CMSDB  and the IModule at the same time and still ensure dependency injection.

The important factor is been able to calve any other solution (a portal maybe) from this later. All opinion is welcome.

Comment: I felt I could pass the service `IModule` into the controller constructor and the IModule to implement the `CMSDB`, the challenge is the Model `Module` and `IModule` are in the same project (a library project) which I feel is not appropriate although.

Comment: Are you aware that "MVC" is a language-independent architectural pattern and **not a name of a framework**?

Comment: I guess you are asking this because of the my website naming? Well, I understand that fully. I only named that as MVC Website so as to remind myself that I have it as a design pattern.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. It seems like a basic StructureMap 101 question. Have you even read their documentation?

Comment: @Mrchief, structuremap works fine. The challenge is my structure.

Comment: What structure? It seems a basic setup. What's not working?

Comment: I have 2 projects in the solution (presentation and Data) layers. I have my models and services serving the models in my data layer (which is a library project), and my database context in my presentation layer (EF using code-first approach). how do I ensure my database context and the service interact and I only have the service in my controller constructor ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you are creating the mapping this should be running on startup

```
   public static class ContainerBootstrapper
    {
        public static void BootstrapStructureMap()
        {
            // Initialize the static ObjectFactory container
            ObjectFactory.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.ForRequestedType<iNTERFACE>().TheDefaultIsConcreteType<ContreteClass>();
            });
        }
    }
```

then

```
  iNTERFACE objectINMVCController = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<iNTERFACE>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the answer marked as the correct answer will work, as this particular question is related to StructureMap 3 it's worth mentioning that using StructureMap's `ObjectFactory` is not recommended and is infact being deprecated in version 4 (as you'll no doubt see when you try and build your solution).

Instead the better alternative is to use StructureMap's `IContainer` interface to compose your dependencies via the below solution:

```
var container = new Container(x => {
    x.For<IInterface>().Use<ConcreteClass>();
    x.For<IInterface2>().Use<ConcreteClass2>();
});
```

As you specifically mention re-usability then I would suggest taking a look at [StructureMap's Registry classes](http://structuremap.github.io/registration/registry-dsl/) that allow you to encapsulate dependencies within a registry like so:

```
public class WebsiteRegistry : Registry
{
    public WebsiteRegistry()
    {
        For<ICustomerService>().Use<CustomerService>();
        For<IProductServer>().Use<ProductService>();
    }
}
```

You can then compose and register your registry classes in the same way via like so:

```
IContainer container = new Container(x =>
{
    x.AddRegistry<DatabaseRegistry>();
    x.AddRegistry<WebsiteRegistry>();
});
```

The benefit of doing it this way is you can break your registry classes into core dependencies, website based dependencies and web service dependencies. For instance, both your website and web service would require database access so this could go into a core registry, however your website might require a `SessionRegistry` that would be useless in a web service (due to a web service's session-less nature).

Then you simply have to register StructureMap with ASP.NET MVC's dependency resolver within the `Global.asax.cs` class.